# Mapping of Cluster result by two different algorithm in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have clustered the `iris` dataset in 3 cluster by two different algorithms. Both of them have provided 3 clusters – 1, 2 and 3. Although visual inspection suggest the mapping “1 -> 3”, “2 -> 2” and “3 -> 1”

Is there any way to map the following two results programmatically?

```
ClustersByMethod1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,3,3,3,3,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,2,3,3,3,3,2,3,3,3,2,3,3,3,2,3,3,2)

ClustersByMethod2 <- c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, in general, not a simple Problem.

If you calculate the correlation between the two vectors, your visual inspection translates into a Matrix with high correlations, but the values Close to 1 are not sitting on the diagonal. So you are searching for a Permutation of the values of, say the second vector, to get the most weight (i.e.the high values close to one) on the diagonal. This will be easy for 3 Clusters, but not for higher numbers of clusters.

There are Methods to solve this Problem (usually by the 'hungarian' algorithm or Munkres-Kuhn), but I don't know about implementations in R.

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: An approach could be, get centers (from main data) of both methods and compare. Nearest/similar centers can be mapped.

Comment: Just saw, Solution is posted at http://www.r-bloggers.com/matching-clustering-solutions-using-the-hungarian-method/